# How can define a 26x2 array and then use LINQ on its rows?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq, data-structures

Grrrr I have C# and multidimensional arrays. For some reason, coming from a C/C++ background, they really annoy me.

So when I run

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{    
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int T = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if(str.Length % 2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(-1);
                continue;
            }
            int n = str.Length / 2;
            // determine how many replacements s1 needs to be an anagram of s2
            string s1 = str.Substring(0, n);
            string s2 = str.Substring(n, n);
            int[][] counter = new int[26][2];
            int ascii_a = (int)'a';
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                counter[(int)s1[i] - ascii_a][0] += 1;
                counter[(int)s2[i] - ascii_a][1] += 1;
            }
            int count = counter.Select((pair => Math.Abs(pair[0] - pair[1]))).Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

I get

> solution.cs(22,42): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int'
>   to`int[][]' Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

No idea why.

I can change it to

```
        int[,] counter = new int[26,2];
        int ascii_a = (int)'a';
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            counter[(int)s1[i] - ascii_a, 0] += 1;
            counter[(int)s2[i] - ascii_a, 1] += 1;
        }
        int count = counter.Select((pair => Math.Abs(pair[0] - pair[1]))).Sum();
```

but then, of course, my LINQ statement breaks.

Comment: `Select((pair =>` - why second `(` before `pair`? At which line you get error?

Comment: @user6048670 Added my version of answer which actually aligns with OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change

```
        int[][] counter = new int[26][2];
```

to

```
        int[][] counter = new int[26][];
        for (int i = 0; i < counter.Length; i++)
            counter[i] = new int[2];
```

code compiles. You can test the rest as you like. As you haven't provided necessary input in OP.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using here is a jagged array, and you can't `new` one like that:

> ```
> int[][] counter = new int[26][2];
> ```

You have to declare the inner array separately :

```
int[][] counter = new int[26][];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    counter[i] = new int[2];
}
```

Alternatively, as @IvanStoev suggested, you can also use a LINQ one liner:

```
var counter = Enumerable.Range(0, 26).Select(_ => new int[2]).ToArray();
```

---

You can also use a 2-dimensional array, such as this one :

```
// notice there is only one bracket
int[,] counter = new int[26,2];
int ascii_a = (int)'a';

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    counter[(int)s1[i] - ascii_a, 0] += 1;
    counter[(int)s2[i] - ascii_a, 1] += 1;
}

// and, you will need to update your query, 
// as linq would implicitly flatten the array
var count = Enumerable.Range(0, 26)
    .Select(x => counter[x, 0] - counter[x, 1])
    .Sum();
```

Comment: You can't assign value to foreach iterations, i.e. pair in this case. You could try something like this though: `int[][] counter = new int[26][];
            for (int i = 0; i < counter.Length; i++)
                counter[i] = new int[2];` As per Linq part, I hope OPer can test and let us know.

Comment: @uteist Correct. Or initialize it with a LINQ one liner like `var counter = Enumerable.Range(0, 26).Select(_ => new int[2]).ToArray();` :)

Comment: @Xiaoy312 You might want to replace `counter[2]` with `counter[i]` btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define jagged array like that:

`int[][] counter = new int[26][2];`

I recommend reading on jagged arrays:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

In your case I'd suggest using not jagged, but multi-dimentional array:

`var counter = new int[26,2];`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining a Counter struct then use an array of those instead of a multi-dimensional array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    struct Counter
    {
        public int c1;
        public int c2;
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int T = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int t = 0; t < T; ++t)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str.Length % 2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(-1);
                continue;
            }
            int n = str.Length / 2;
            // determine how many replacements s1 needs to be an anagram of s2
            string s1 = str.Substring(0, n);
            string s2 = str.Substring(n, n);
            Counter[] counter = new Counter[26];
            int ascii_a = (int)'a';
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                counter[(int)s1[i] - ascii_a].c1 += 1;
                counter[(int)s2[i] - ascii_a].c2 += 1;
            }
            int count = counter.Select((pair => Math.Abs(pair.c1 - pair.c2))).Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```